# Redirect From REST_API Response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Angular and Django in my stack for a website, and after a user registers it emails them a link to activate their account. As of right now everything is working but the link takes the user to the Django rest framework page.

I've been returning responses in my app like this

```
data = {'success': True, 'message': 'An account has been activated.', 'response': {}}
return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I am curious on how to redirect a user back to the login page which at the current moment would be a localhost page such as http://localhost:4200/#/authentication/login.

From research I have found methods like

```
return redirect('http://localhost:4200/#/authentication/login')
```

but I am wanting to keep my responses consistent. Is there a way to redirect a user while still using the rest api Response object?

Comment: you not make urls.py file?if yes then share with me please

Comment: AFAIK, you cant perform both on your views.

Comment: This should be done in Angular. Not in Django.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about the comment posted by Muhammad Hassan, I realized I was thinking about this all wrong. Instead of sending a Django url I have change the email to send a URL to an Angular page I made and then I just sent an HTTP request from that page to the Django URL.